# C++ change canonical mode in windows

Tags: c++, include

After finding a bunch of threads on this I did not find any on Windows, only Linux, Ubuntu etc.

In short what I am trying to find out is how to turn canonical mode off so that input in the console results in instant input without having to press enter.

Longer version. This is what I am trying to do right now:
When the PGM is pausing (text based game) the user is asked to enter an arrow key to move the player around on the 2D array. But `cin.get()`, `cin.ignore()` and some other things I've tried all require pressing enter before it will continue.

The infamous `system("pause>nul");` *does* actually work, but as I've read in various other places is very bad practice.

This is part of the code. the `cout` statements are only for testing purpose:

```
//While loop
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)){
        cout << "up" << endl;
}
else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)){
        cout << "down" << endl;
}
else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)){
        cout << "left" << endl;
}
else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)){
        cout << "right" << endl;
}
else{
    break;}

//pauze and check for arrow key input here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getch` also on windows:

I know it is C, and you got the deprecated warning, but it works...

this code run in a loop till you press Enter:

check what happen when you press an arrow key...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main ()
{
  int c;
  do {
    c=getch();
    printf("%d\n",c);
  } while (c != 13);
  return 0;
}
```