# Why does switch always run default? (with break; included)

Tags: c++, windows, switch-statement

C++ newbie trying to make a simple text game on a 2D array.

When I use the `switch` statement as shown. It will always print the default value, regardless of what else happens.

From other threads and forums I found it probably has something to do with the `getch()` and that it returns the `char` as well as `\n`.

I have tried for an hour now but I can not solve this. The reason I use `getch()` is this: [C++ change canonical mode in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262287/c-change-canonical-mode-in-windows) (for reference).

Part of my code now:

```
//Set up game field
generateField();
setPlayerStart();

//printGameInfo(); TO BE MADE

//Start game while loop
int userInput;

do{
    //system("cls"); DISABLED FOR TESTING PURPOSES
    printField();
    userInput = getch();

    switch(userInput){
        case 72:{ //ARROW UP
            cout << "1What" << endl; //ALSO FOR TESTING PURPOSES
            break;
        }

        case 80:{ //ARROW DOWN
            cout << "2What" << endl;
            break;
        }

        case 75:{ //ARROW LEFT
            cout << "3What" << endl;
            break;
        }

        case 77:{ //ARROW RIGHT
            cout << "4What" << endl;
            break;
        }

        case 113:{ //"q"
            return false; //Quit game
        }

        default:{
            cout << "Default..." << endl;
        }
    }
} while(userInput != 5);
```

Comment: You don't have a `default`, do you?

Comment: 72 is more likely `H`. `getch` doesn't read keypresses, it reads characters.

Comment: Wow, my bad. Ctrl-C Ctrl-V is not that easy apparently. Edited

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; I thought `getchar` that's why :P

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast is right; you've decided that `72` means "arrow up", but the universe doesn't agree.

Comment: By the way, that answer to the "canonical mode" should be changed to say `SetConsoleMode` to disable line input. It is perfectly possible to "read keypresses" by using `ReadConsoleInput`.

Comment: When you have a `default` case that shouldn't happen often and outputs some sort of log or debugging message, include the actual variable that got you to the `default` in the first place.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast @LightnessRacesinOrbit Whether that is true or not, it is working. I'ts just running everything twice so once the arrow key and then `\n` which runs to default.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I what? Perhaps you pinged the wrong person, but I was just going by the huge `//ARROW UP` comment.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast: I said that you're right. Then I went into more detail about what you were pointing out.

Comment: @LuukV: That's a strange attitude to take. "Even if it's true that I got it wrong, it's right"??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's not what I mean to say. I suppose I don't understand what you're saying, since when I press the up key, it does run through the `case 72:` and then how can it not be correct?

Comment: When I test this in Windows I see that pressing the up arrow key causes two key to be read, 224, 72.  It would seem that ignoring the 224 value would do what you want.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Or, better yet, recognizing the sequence sent by the arrow keys. Ignoring *anything* is likely to cause problems.

Comment: The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) don't seem to attach any significance to the extra value, just state that it is there.  I'd just consider 0 and 0xe0 as dead keys.

Comment: @LuukV, I have to apologize as my above comment is wrong. When I said `getch` doesn't read keypresses, I forgot it's not portable and that it doesn't simply store the result of something that has a code point. Also, I later realized `SetConsoleMode` is unimportant as `ReadConsoleInput` does not use line input anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is Windows, you can use [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read key events. I've separated the parts into functions, but I don't really think the return semantics of `handleInput` is all that great.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE getStdinHandle() {
    HANDLE hIn;
    if ((hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get standard input handle.");
    }

    return hIn;
}

WORD readVkCode(HANDLE hIn) {
    INPUT_RECORD rec;
    DWORD numRead;
    while (ReadConsoleInput(hIn, &rec, 1, &numRead) && numRead == 1) {
        if (rec.EventType == KEY_EVENT && rec.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) {
            return rec.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read input.");
}

bool handleInput(WORD vk) {
    switch (vk) {
        case VK_UP:
            std::cout << "up\n";
            break;

        case VK_DOWN:
            std::cout << "down\n";
            break;

        case VK_LEFT:
            std::cout << "left\n";
            break;

        case VK_RIGHT:
            std::cout << "right\n";
            break;

        case 'Q': //it's Windows; ASCII is safe
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    try {
        auto hIn = getStdinHandle();

        while (auto vk = readVkCode(hIn)) {
            if (handleInput(vk)) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Other useful links:

- [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`INPUT_RECORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`KEY_EVENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for api-based solution - `getch` looks legacy and old, isn't it?

Comment: @ikh, It's from `conio.h` and meant for DOS, so yes.

Comment: especially `getch()` - it's wide-used despite that o^o

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time for this answer. Looks really good but is quite a bit over my head. I will look again tomorrow since it's now 1AM and I'll go through the documentation then. Thanks again.

Comment: @LuukV, It's a lot easier when you've been reading Windows API documentation for a couple years, but yeah, it's just following documentation and checking for errors (which I thought would be useful to include, but I didn't go so far as to use `std::system_error` or `GetLastError`).

Answer (score 4):

Um, I assume you've forgotten how to receive extended keys..

It comes with `0xe0` when extended keys, and it comes with `0x00` when function key (F1-F12)

Change it

```
userInput = getch();
```

into

```
userInput = getch();
if (userInput == 0xe0) // for extended keys
{
    userInput = getch();
}
else if (userInput == 0x00) // for function keys
{
    userInput = getch();
}
```

Comment: This *always* ignores the first key. What if you want to recognize, say, letters or digits?

Comment: @KeithThompson As I said - It's how to receive extended keys. If you want to receive both normal and extended keys, you should `userInput = getch(); if (userInput == 0xe0) userInput = getch();`

Comment: The extra value might be 0 as well, at least it is for F1-F10.

Comment: I'm saying you should pay attention to *both* results returned by `getch()`. With your approach, quietly ignoring the `0xe0`, you can't distinguish between up arrow and `H`. The code should recognize an up arrow if and only if it sees `0xe0` followed by `'H'`.

Comment: @ikh From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) and a quick test program.  Good point about the sequence, I didn't think about the conflict before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get that it isn't a full-proof solution, but sure is workable for now.