# How to get input

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to make a number guessing game.
I need to store the input of up arrow key, down arrow key and enter

```
std::cin >> i;
std::cout << i;
```

When I do this nothing happens.

How do I do it and what type of variable is needed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/5910058

Comment: There isn't a standard way of capturing arrow keys. It depends on your platform.

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Detect when user presses arrow key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708700/c-detect-when-user-presses-arrow-key)

Comment: @JesperJuhl, very subtle, lol.

Comment: *I need to store the input of up arrow key, down arrow key and enter* -- Why do you need these specific keys for a "number guessing game"?  Why not use the regular letter keys for specific input tasks?

Comment: @anastaciu what more needs to be said?

Comment: @JesperJuhl touché.